# display JQuery variable in html

Tags: html, ajax

This is my_js.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("fetch.php", function (data) {
        $("ul").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            var name = this['sender_name'];
            var age = this['sender_age'];
            var photo = this['sender_photo'];
            var language = this['sender_language'];
            var country = this['sender_country'];
            var message = this['message'];
            $('div.haha').html('<p>This is the message ' + message 
                + ' my name is ' + name + ' my age ' + age + ' my language ' 
                + language + ' my country ' + country + '</p>');
        });
    });
}
```

and the html code is

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul></ul>
        <div class="haha"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

all those variables can not displayed in html div , all variables was loaded successfully from fetch.PHP .

Comment: Your ready function isn't properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your success function should be a separate argument:

```
$.getJSON("fetch.php", function (data) {
    $("ul").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function () {
        var name = this['sender_name'];
        var age = this['sender_age'];
        var photo = this['sender_photo'];
        var language = this['sender_language'];
        var country = this['sender_country'];
        var message = this['message'];
    });

    $('div.haha').html('<p>This is the message ' + message + ' my name is ' 
        + name + ' my age ' + age + ' my language ' + language + ' my country ' 
        + country + '</p>');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

Place the src you xtracted in a var

```
    var photolink = photo <!---- This is what you extracted from the database --->

   <!----- This will place to that img with class asd the src atributre from the var ----> 
        photolink =   $('.asd').attr('src');

        <div>
           <img class="asd" src="">
        </div>
```

Might work!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `text()` method instead of `html()` method,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("fetch.php", function (data) {
        $("ul").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            var name = this['sender_name'];
            var age = this['sender_age'];
            var photo = this['sender_photo'];
            var language = this['sender_language'];
            var country = this['sender_country'];
            var message = this['message'];

            $('div.haha').text('This is the message ' + message 
             + ' my name is ' + name + ' my age ' + age + ' my language ' 
             + language + ' my country ' + country);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: when i try my code that i posted above i get that:This is the message: hello
my name is: undefined
my age: undefined
my language: undefined
my country: undefined

Comment: you close `});` before  `$('div.haha').text(...)'  so remove this. and try again

Comment: the problem was in the php file because i ad this 'array_push($result, array('message' => $row['msg']));' as a result something like two array inside one if you know what i mean thanks anyway for your help , and have a nice day.

Comment: oky same 2 u good day, and give me vote credit to help me future.